# In NLTK, get the number of occurrences of a trigram

Tags: python, nltk

I'd like to get the "commonly used phrases" from a text, defined as the trigrams which occur more than once. Till now I have this:

```
import nltk

def get_words(string):
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    return tokenizer.tokenize(string)

string = "Hello, world. This is a dog. This is a cat."

words = get_words(string)

finder = nltk.collocations.TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
scored = finder.score_ngrams(nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures().raw_freq)
```

The resulting `scored` is

```
[(('This', 'is', 'a'), 0.2), (('Hello', 'world', 'This'), 0.1), (('a', 'dog', 'This'), 0.1), (('dog', 'This', 'is'), 0.1), (('is', 'a', 'cat'), 0.1), (('is', 'a', 'dog'), 0.1), (('world', 'This', 'is'), 0.1)]
```

I've noticed that the number in the elements of `scored` is the number of occurrences of the trigram divided by the total word count (in this case, 10). Is there a way to get the number of occurrences directly, without 'post-multiplying' by the word count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK - Counting Frequency of Bigram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145332/nltk-counting-frequency-of-bigram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get number of occurrences using **finder.ngram_fd.items()**

```
# To get Trigrams with occurrences
trigrams = finder.ngram_fd.items()
print trigrams

# To get Trigrams with occurrences in descending order
trigrams = sorted(finder.ngram_fd.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
print trigrams
```

You can check more related examples at : [NLTK Collocations](http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get frequencies with normalization you can just call ngram_fd.
In your case:

```
trigram_freqs = finder.ngram_fd
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with 'post-multiplying' the `raw_freq` attribute because it is already sorted. Here is my implementation:

```
import nltk

def get_words(string):
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    return tokenizer.tokenize(string)

string = "Hello, world. This is a dog. This is a cat."

words = get_words(string)
word_count = len(words)

finder = nltk.collocations.TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
scored = finder.score_ngrams(nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures().raw_freq)
scored_common = filter(lambda score: score[1]*word_count > 1, scored)
common_phrases = [" ".join(score[0]) for score in scored_common]
```

This yields the common phrases as `['This is a']` for this example.